# Google App Engine Python django TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'endif'

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I keep getting this error when using django templates in Google App Engine:

TemplateSyntaxError: Invalid block tag: 'endif'

python code:

```
class SuperAdmin(webapp.RequestHandler):
def get(self):

    #set the user object
    user = users.get_current_user()

    # See if user is logged in
    if user:  # signed in already
        #Create Logout URL
        logoutUrl = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
        template_values['logoutUrl'] = logoutUrl

        #is this user a super admin
        isSuperAdmin = acl_authentication.AuthenticateUserViaAcl().isUserSuperAdmin(user.email(), user.user_id())
        template_values['isSuperAdmin'] = isSuperAdmin

        #Use our auth object to see if the user is allowed on this page
        if acl_authentication.AuthenticateUserViaAcl().IsUserPermitted(user.user_id(), user.email(), '0', '0', 50): #User is allowed
            self.response.out.write("This user is in the acl db and a super admin<br/>")

            #Add action1 to template_values
            template_values['action1'] = self.request.get('action1')

            #Write the Header
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'adminHeader.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

            #Write the Login Page
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'SuperAdmin.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

            #Write the Header
            path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'adminFooter.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))

        else: #User is not allowed
            #Log to DB that we hit access denied page
            acl_authentication.AuthenticateUserViaAcl().LogToDbAccessDeniedHit(user.user_id(), user.email(), self.request.url)
            #Redirect to Access Denied Page
            self.redirect("/AccessDeniedPage")

    else: #User is not logged in
        self.redirect("/LoginPage?destUrl=" + self.request.url)
```

.html template code

```
<!-- Begin If action1==manage_companies -->
                {% if action1 == "manage_companies" % }
                    <tr>
                      <td>Manage Companies</td>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                      <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                {% endif %}
<!-- /End If action1==manage_companies -->
```

I'm not familiar with django so im lost here. Thanks

Comment: It seems like there is a space between '%' and '}' in your closing tag of `{% if ...` in your template. It should be '%}' instead of '% }'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's an extra space between '%' and '}' in this line
`{% if action1 == "manage_companies" % }`
try changing it to
 `{% if action1 == "manage_companies" %}`

Comment: That did fix this error but raised another one, i had to use the syntax {% ifequal %} and {% endifequal %}. Do i need to be using a different django library than the default?